# Rotating planets with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a project where I am creating some planets and they need to rotate. I am a beginner currently in school. I found some code that rotates but It starts to skip. The alternative is to have it alternate in rotating but then that doesn't look right.

How can I fix this with CSS?

```css
.earth {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 20px #000 inset, 0 0 20px 2px #000;
}

.earth:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: -20px -20px 50px 2px #000 inset;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.earth > div {
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: spin 30s linear infinite;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SLqF.jpg);
    /*orginal image at https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c4/Earthmap1000x500compac.jpg/640px-Earthmap1000x500compac.jpg */
    background-size: cover;
}

@keyframes spin {
    to {
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="earth">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Here is the GIF image of the issue: https://imgur.com/a/f7nUtrW//

Comment: I think you are looking for CSS solution and not JS solution, as wanted to clear you do not need JS for this to work, CSS could make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make the width `400%` and not `200%` and instead of `cover` use `auto 100%`.

I have optimized the code a little so you can easily adjust the dimension and keep the circular shape:

```css
.earth {
  width: 300px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 20px #000 inset, 0 0 20px 2px #000;
  position:relative;
}
.earth:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: -20px -20px 50px 2px #000 inset;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.earth::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 400%;
  padding-top:100%;
  animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
  background: url(https://github.com/BHouwens/SolarSim/blob/master/images/earthmap1k.jpg?raw=true);
  background-size: auto 100%;
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="earth">
</div>

<div class="earth" style="width:200px">
</div>

<div class="earth" style="width:100px">
</div>
```

Also like below with less of code and no pseudo element:

```css
.earth {
  --d:300px;
  width: var(--d);
  height:var(--d);
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: -20px -20px 50px 2px #000 inset, 0 0 20px 2px #000;
  background: 
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SLqF.jpg)
    0/auto 100%;
  animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {
    background-position:200% 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="earth">
</div>

<div class="earth" style="--d:200px">
</div>

<div class="earth" style="--d:100px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add two stages to the keyframe specifying the x-position, as such:

```
@keyframes spin{
  0% { background-position-x: 0; } 
  100% { background-position-x: -600px; }
}
```

I've added an snippet with the result:

```css
.earth {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 20px #000 inset, 0 0 20px 2px #000;
}

.earth:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: -20px -20px 50px 2px #000 inset;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.earth > div {
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
    background: url(https://github.com/BHouwens/SolarSim/blob/master/images/earthmap1k.jpg?raw=true);
    /*orginal image at https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c4/Earthmap1000x500compac.jpg/640px-Earthmap1000x500compac.jpg */
    background-size: cover;
}
@keyframes spin{
  0% { background-position-x: 0; } 
  100% { background-position-x: -600px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="earth">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see my attempt [here](https://codepen.io/athelian/pen/NWBzXVO), and the [accompanying article](https://medium.com/@ejaustinforbes/making-a-sassy-earth-5fcad12b0856)! Here is the pug (sass is hundreds of lines)

```
- const randomNumber = ({ min, max }) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
- const planetDiameter = 50;
- const cloudLayers = 3;
- const earth = [{"label": "Africa", "layers": 20, "diameter": 26 * (50 / 42), "rotation": -8, "z-rotation": 14, "position": 10, "components": 1},{"label": "Asia", "layers": 20, "diameter": 38 * (50 / 42), "rotation": -4, "z-rotation": -45, "position": 1919, "components": 7},{"label": "Europe", "layers": 20, "diameter": 21 * (50/42), "rotation": 0, "z-rotation": 10, "position": 520, "components": 8},{"label": "America", "layers": 20, "diameter": 41 * (50/42), "rotation": 20, "z-rotation": 140, "position": 560, "components": 4},{"label": "Australasia", "layers": 20, "diameter": 24 * (50 / 42), "rotation": -10, "z-rotation": -89, "position": 1, "components": 24}];
- const clouds = [{"label": "A", "randomY": randomNumber({min: 0, max: 36}) * 10, "randomZ": randomNumber({min: -50, max: 50}), "center-to-apex": -95, "width": "632.15px", "height": "271.38px"}, {"label": "B", "randomY": randomNumber({min: 0, max: 36}) * 10, "randomZ": randomNumber({min: -50, max: 50}), "center-to-apex": 0, "width": "762.01px", "height": "301.12px"}, { "label": "C","randomY": randomNumber({min: 0, max: 36}) * 10, "randomZ": randomNumber({min: -50, max: 50}), "center-to-apex": 0, "width": "737.64px", "height": "409.58px"}, {"label": "D", "randomY": randomNumber({min: 0, max: 36}) * 10, "randomZ": randomNumber({min: -50, max: 50}), "center-to-apex": 0, "width": "778.11px", "height": "406.46px"}, {"label": "E", "randomY": randomNumber({min: 0, max: 36}) * 10, "randomZ": randomNumber({min: -50, max: 50}), "center-to-apex": 130, "width": "750.41px", "height": "391.78px"}];
- const cloudsComputed = Array(randomNumber({ min: 10, max: 20 })).fill("").map(() => { const randomZ = randomNumber({ min: -50, max: 50 }); const randomY = randomNumber({ min: 0, max: 36 }) * 10; const randomCloud = clouds[randomNumber({ min: 0, max: clouds.length - 1 })].label; const randomScale = randomNumber({ min: 21, max: 30 }); return { randomZ, randomY, randomCloud, randomScale };});

.Earth
.Earth__Earth-Container
 .Planet.Planet--Earth
   .Sphere
     .Hemisphere
       each continent in earth
         div(class=`Island Island--${continent.label}`)
           - var layers = continent.layers - 1;
           while layers > 0
             - layers--
             .Plate
               div
                 - var components = continent.components;
                 while components > 0
                   - components--
                     .Land

.Earth__Clouds
 each cloud in cloudsComputed
   div(class=`Planet Planet--Clouds Planet--Clouds--y-rotation--${cloud.randomY}`)
     .Sphere
       div(class="Hemisphere" style={"transform": `rotateY(${cloud.randomY}deg) rotateZ(${cloud.randomZ}deg)`})
         div(class=`Island Cloud Cloud--${cloud.randomCloud} Cloud--scale-${cloud.randomScale}`)
           - var layers = cloudLayers;
           while layers > 0
             - layers--
               div
```